# Need help in apply kibana query

Tags: kibana

I want to know the query for kibana, i tried terms and agg, but didnt get right output, so need to filter the data based on distinct query in kibana.

I want to apply query in following input data in elasticsearch

Rows and columns

### CELLID|MCC|MNC|

### 1222|405|861|

### 1222|405|861|

### 1222|405|122|

### 1233|406|861|

### 1233|406|861|

### 1224|407|777|

1224|407|777|

need to apply query such a way, it will remove the same CELL ID with different MNC, so expecting output like this

### CELLID|MCC|MNC|

### 1233|406|861|

### 1233|406|861|

### 1224|407|777|

1224|407|777|

Comment: If you could show how have you handled **terms & aggs** in `Kibana`?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, it's impossible to have such *row* vs *column* infrastructure within `Kibana` graphs as of now. Cos this [feature](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3620) is yet be made to the new versions as an enhancement.

But then if you're simply trying to print out the `count|sum` or let it be whatever the *aggregation* you need, you can have a **Data Table** visualization with a *metric* of count and then within your **buckets** you could define multiple *terms-aggregation*. In your case, you should have `CELLID|MCC|MNC` being split by *terms-aggregation* which should do the job for you. Hope this helps!